# WebServiceTemplate - difference between Interceptor and Callback?

Tags: java, callback, interceptor, spring-ws, webservicetemplate

I'm trying to write my first client using Spring-WS and am getting a little confused at some basics. I need to insert a SAML token into the header, and I've noticed that the WebServiceTemplate class allows for both Interceptors and WebServiceMessageCallbacks.

Can someone please help me understand why I should use one versus another?

Secondly, I noticed that the WST class allows for a list of interceptors, but only a single callback. Does anyone know what the logic was behind that design decision? Why is there no ability to pass an array or list of Callbacks?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering the same after reading your question (-:

On [this link](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?60153-Difference-between-an-Interceptor-and-a-WebServiceMessageCallback) there's a brief explanation and that's exactly how I use both. For instance, for a specific request I need to set the SOAP action:

```
JAXBElement<Response> response = (JAXBElement<Response>) webserviceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(
    request, 
    new SoapActionCallback("PutOrganisationUnitRequest")
);
```

This is indeed a simple, anonymous class as mentioned in the link. An interceptor on the other hand is defined and used for all requests. Take a look at [XwsSecurityInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/xwss/XwsSecurityInterceptor.html) for instance, I use that to set the authentication on ALL requests.